# Using different ways to implement the same function in tensorflow will get the same gradient?

Tags: tensorflow

For example, I want to implement the leaky relu.

There are two ways:

- The first way:

> x = tf.where(tf.greater(x, 0.0), x, alpha*x)

- The second way:

> mask = tf.cast(tf.greater(x, 0.0), dtype=tf.float32)
>
> x = 1.0 * mask * x + alpha * (1 - mask) * x

Will two ways have the same backpropagation?

Comment: I understand this is not your question, but why not write Leaky-RELU with `tf.maximum(x, alpha * x)` ?

Comment: Yeah, maybe there are many ways to implements leaky_relu, but I want to ask is the gradient of them the same?

Answer (score 0):

The theoretical answer: If two functions are the same, meaning that they produce exactly the same outputs for all given inputs, then the gradients of the two functions will also be exactly the same.

In practice, I guess this doesn't hold because of numerical imprecisions when multiplying the gradients of several functions. But the differences should stay small for reasonable functions.